# spark 1.6 column to json

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a spark Dataset which has as column with struct data type and need to convert that to JSON, I made the implementation using to_json in spark 2.1 but unfortunately our production environment only supports spark 1.6, which has no to_json implementation. I am using Java 8.